# c++ - Inserting 3 variable values into a multimap

Tags: c++, dictionary, syntax, insert, multimap

I'm new to the use of maps and multimaps, and I'm having trouble (compiler errors and warnings) when trying to insert 3 values into a multimap via the use of a pair of strings (acting as the key) and an int value:

This is my multimap declaration:

```
multimap<pair<string, string>, int> wordpairs;
```

This is how I'm trying to populate the multimap:

```
int toInsert = 0;

  for (int i = 0; i < s; i++) {

    wordpairs.insert((words[i], words[i+1]), toInsert);

  }
```

where words is:

```
vector<string> words
```

I'm getting this error and a bunch of warnings:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘std::multimap<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >, int>::insert(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>&, int&)’
     wordpairs.insert((words[i], words[i+1]), toInsert);
                                                      ^
```

Not sure how to properly insert the values I want to. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use this `wordpairs.insert( make_pair(make_pair(words[i], words[i+1]), toInsert));`

Comment: In this situation, emplace makes more sense.

Comment: I got a slightly less verbose version with this, though it needs c++11: `wordpairs.emplace(std::make_pair(words[i], words[i+1]), toInsert);`

Answer (score 1):

Your key is a pair (`pair<string, string>`) and `(words[i], words[i+j])` is not a pair. You'll need `wordpairs.emplace(std::make_pair(words[i], words[i+j]), toInsert)`

Edit: There are two ways to put something into a map (or multimap). The first is insert in which it needs an object to copy into your map. Your map contains a pair of < pair< string,string >, int >. So you could call insert like... `wordpairs.insert(std::make_pair(std::make_pair(words[i], words[i+j]), toInsert))` OR you can emplace them. Emplace constructs the object in place, so instead of constructing it with `make_pair` and then copying it into the map, you can just construct it in place with the given call.

Comment: I tried that and I'm still getting the same error. :(

Answer (score 1):

The [insert member function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap/insert) only expects one argument.

```
wordpairs.insert((words[i], words[i+1]), toInsert);
```

provides at least two. It is not valid grammar (I think, the comma operator may or may not be valid in this context.).

The insert is expecting a pair, {key, value},  Your key is a pair {words[i], words[i+1]} combined this yields with the magic of uniform initialization:

```
    wordpairs.insert({{words[i], words[i+1]}, toInsert});
```

This requires C++11.

Additional reading as to why this works is found in [a very popular *softwareengineering* question.](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/133688/is-c11-uniform-initialization-a-replacement-for-the-old-style-syntax)